# Grouping distinct values of same index in muldimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, distinct, multidimensional-array

i got an array like this:

```
    array(28) { 
[0]=> array(8) { ["jornada"]=> string(1) "1" ["team1"]=> string(12) "LEGANES F.C." ["team2"]=> string(9) "LAS CONOS" }
[1]=> array(8) { ["jornada"]=> string(1) "1" ["team1"]=> string(13) "BABACHAS F.C." ["team2"]=> string(19) "QUIRQUINCHAS VERDES" }
[2]=> array(8) { ["jornada"]=> string(1) "2" ["team1"]=> string(7) "TSU CHU" ["team2"]=> string(12) "SANTINO F.C." } 
[3]=> array(8) { ["jornada"]=> string(1) "2" ["team1"]=> string(11) "LIBERO F.C." ["team2"]=> string(9) "LAS PUMAS" } 
[4]=> array(8) { ["jornada"]=> string(1) "3" ["team1"]=> string(6) "PUCARA" ["team2"]=> string(15) "EL REJUNTE F.C." }
```

my question is, how can i get the differents "jornada's" values? because i have to make a fixture grouping by "jornada" something like :

```
jornada 1 :
LEGANES vs LAS CONOS
BABACHAS vs QUIRQUINCHAS

jornada 2: 
TSU CHU vs SANTINO
LIBERO vs LAS PUMAS
```

thanks for your help and sorry about my english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could re-arrange them into a new array that has this grouping...

```
$grouped = array();
foreach ($data as $row) {
    $grouped[$row['jornada']][] = $row;
}
```

now you can do:

```
foreach ($grouped as $jorndada => $matches) {
    echo "Jornada $jornada\n";
    foreach ($matches as $match) {
        echo $match["team1"] ." vs ". $match["team2"] . PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```